# AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
**job model**
class JobPost(models.Model):
        creater = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        job_type = models.ForeignKey(
            JobType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        job_loc = models.ForeignKey(JobLocation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        cmpny_name = models.ForeignKey(
            Company, related_name='company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        job_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.job_type)
```

**company serializer**

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
```

**post serializer**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # job_loc = JoblocationSerializer(many=True)
    companies = CompanySerializer(source='company', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = JobPost
        fields = '__all__'
```

**error i am getting**

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for
> field `companies` on serializer `PostSerializer`. The serializer field
> might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the
> `JobPost` instance. Original exception text was: 'JobPost' object has
> no attribute 'company'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the source attribute you need to put the relationship name from JobPost side, since its called `cmpny_name` you should use that.

and you shouldn't use `many=True` kwarg since its a ForiegnKey relationship from JobPost side each post will only be related to a single company.

so with all that together it will be:

```
cmpny_name = CompanySerializer()
```

Comment: thanks worked like charm i was stuck into it for hours

Comment: what is source used for than in reverse relations i was a bit confused about it , tried to rea about it

Comment: it can be used to get the value of any callable or attribute from within the model itself, or even you can get nested attributes from the model